# Cookbook site share command for Private Supermarket is connecting to Public Supermarket

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

When I am running the command to upload cookbook on my private supermarket installation , it is always trying to connect to "supermarket.chef.io" , even though I have added `knife[:supermarket_site] = 'https://ip-205-5-117.dqa.capitalone.com/'` to my knife.rb

Command that I am trying to run:

```
knife cookbook site share myfirstcookbook "others" -c knife.rb -VV
```

Log is :

```
workstation:test zng937$ knife cookbook site share  myfirstcookbook "Web Servers" -c knife.rb 
Generating metadata for myfirstcookbook from /var/folders/6s/vb0m1sqd1hldg7thk6m3dflmv7dc2h/T/chef-myfirstcookbook-build20160106-7998-r5y7kx/myfirstcookbook/metadata.rb
Making tarball myfirstcookbook.tgz
ERROR: Error uploading cookbook myfirstcookbook to the Opscode Cookbook Site: Operation timed out - connect(2) for "supermarket.chef.io" port 443. Increase log verbosity (-VV) for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using the `knife-supermarket` plugin: https://github.com/chef/knife-supermarket